# Where is Flutter app data located on macOS

Tags: macos, flutter

Where can I find my app's data, such as cache, temp, preferences, databases, etc. on macOS?

I would like to clear this data to reset my app.

On Android, this can be done from an app's settings page by clicking the "Clear data" button.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`~/Library/Containers/your-app-name`

Tip: Open Finder, `CMD` + `Shift` + `G`, paste `~/Library/Containers`, Go.